# Paired with hc 05 but not connected

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno

## Main Problem

My mobile phone is already paired with my HC-05 bluetooth module. But the problem is it is not connected.

Do you have any solution about this kind of problem guys?

Need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It will connect only when requested, for example, while using a bluetooth terminal application. Try searching for a bluetooth terminal app in the google play store, install, then you should be able to connect.